# Boot with Radeon 9600

Tags: installation, boot, graphics, mac

I'm trying to boot in to the live environment but i get a odd cloud of colour. I'm guessing There is something up with the graphics card. I've tried video=ofonly. I managed to get to the command line as ubuntu@ubuntu.

I would like to use the graphical installer as I'm new to linux and, for now, a command based install is a little out of my comfort zone.

I've got a ATI Radeon 9600 with 128 MB of DDR SDRAM in my PowerMac G5 if that helps.

I've got an image but I've not got the rating to uploaded it.

[I've uploaded it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gorSm.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indeed try using the alternate (text) installer. Don't be scared, even though it is text it is completely menu based, there is no command line involved. Basically the installer draws some kind of graphical windows using text characters.

Once Ubuntu is installed you will probably have access to proprietary drivers which anable your graphics card.

If you are still scared of the installer you should maybe find a local Linux User Group. There is one in almost every city of the planet. The folks there can help you hands on.